# Address of a member data stored on heap memory

Tags: pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm learning C++ and I've got a question, about the material that I'm using. I think that there may be some errors in editing, but I'm quite not sure. My book's name is "C++ through game programming".

Here's the code in the book, it's in chapter 9.

```
class Critter {
public:
    Critter(const string &name = "", int age = 0);
    ~Critter();
    Critter(const Critter &c);
    Critter& operator=(const Critter& c);
    void greet() const;

private:
    string *mName;
    int mAge;
};

Critter::Critter(const string &name, int age) {
    cout << "Constructor called\n";
    mName = new string(name);
    mAge = age;
}

Critter::~Critter() {
    cout << "Destructor called\n";
    delete mName;
}

Critter::Critter(const Critter &c) {
    cout << "Copy constructor called\n";
    mName = new string(*(c.mName));
    mAge = c.mAge;
}


Critter& Critter::operator=(const Critter& c) {
    cout << "Overloading assignment operator called\n";
    if (this != &c) {
        delete mName;
        mName = new string(*(c.mName));
        mAge = c.mAge;
    }
    return *this;
}

void Critter::greet() const {
    cout << "I'm " << *mName << " and I'm " << mAge << " years old.\n";
    cout << "&mName: " << &mName << endl;
}
```

Here I'm creating a Critter class, and test for allocate heap memory. As you can see, I declared a pointer *mName that point to a string object on the heap memory.

So what is confusing me now is that, in the last method:
    void Critter::greet() const
They say that "the address of the string on the heap stored in the pointer m_pName" is &mName, as they print it out in the method.

But I think that mName itself is the address of the string object stored on the heap. So &mName is the address of the pointer itself.

To make it clear, I try to print &mAge also.

And what I got is:

```
&mName: 0x7fff5fbff640
mName: 0x100103b20
&mAge: 0x7fff5fbff648
```

As you can see, &mName and &mAge have nearly similar address, but mName's is different. So maybe mName points to the heap, and &mName and &mAge are actually the addresses that belong to the stack.

That's what I think, I tried to find the errata of that book but I found nothing. Can you guys make it clear for me. Was I right or might I have some misunderstanding.

Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You do have it right. Because `mName` is a pointer, the value of that pointer is the address of the string object that it points to. `&mName` is the address where the pointer itself is stored.